# execute commands from another program from a python script

Tags: java, python, input, console, communication

Unable to communicate from a python script with java program.
I have a java program that reads from standard input.
Logic is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ...
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  String cmd;
  boolean salir = faslse

  while (!salir) {
    cmd = in.readLine();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "run: " + cmd);
    //execute cmd
    ... 
    System.out.println(result);
    System.out.flush();
  }

}
```

I run the program through the console console

> java -cp MyProgram.jar package.MyMainClass

And execute commands and get results, and shows the command executed in a dialogue (JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "run: " + cmd); )

I need to call the program from python.
Right now I'm trying with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen("java -cp MyProgram.jar package.MyMainClass", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE , stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
print '1- create ok'
p.stdin.write('comand parameter1 parameter2')
print '2- writeComand ok'
p.stdin.flush()
print '3- flush ok'
result = p.stdout.readline()  # this line spoils the script
print '4- readline ok'
print result
p.stdin.close()
p.stdout.close()
print 'end'
```

And the output is

```
1- create ok
2- writeComand ok
3- flush ok
```

And does not show the dialog.

however if I run:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen("java -cp MyProgram.jar package.MyMainClass", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE , stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
print '1- create ok'
p.stdin.write('comand parameter1 parameter2')
print '2- writeComand ok'
p.stdin.flush()
print '3- flush ok'
p.stdin.close()
p.stdout.close()
print 'end'
```

the output is

```
1- create ok
2- writeComand ok
3- flush ok
end
```

and show show the dialog.

the line  p.stdout.readline() spoils the script, as I can fix this?

Thank you very much any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flush your `System.out` after printing just one `result`.

Additionally change your code to do this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("java -cp MyProgram.jar package.MyMainClass",
    shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write(command1)
p.stdin.flush()  # this should trigger the processing in the Java process
result = p.stdout.readline()  # this only proceeds if the Java process flushes
p.stdin.write(command2)
p.stdin.flush()
result = p.stdout.readline()
# and afterwards:
p.stdin.close()
p.stdout.close()
```

Comment: in the java code? The java code works fine. I run it from the console and get the expected results. The problem is with the python script. thanks

Comment: Yes, in the Java code.  When writing to a terminal, different buffering is applied by all processes.  When writing to a pipe (instead of a tty), the Java process assumes that this is a bulk data connection and flushes only when the buffer is exhausted.  Insert that flushing and try again.

Comment: I tried that and not make it. The problem is with the python code. I can not run the commands in the java interpreter. thanks

Comment: Hm, maybe I misunderstood.  Please describe the misbehavior you experience in more detail.  Do you get an error message?  An exception?  A stack trace?  Or a non-reaction like a hanging process?

Comment: Did you try adding a newline to your command?  Or how does the Java process recognize a complete command?

Comment: ok, sorry. Java program runs but does not run any command. I think the script waits to finish the program, but the script does not print any results.

Comment: Yeah, I think `communicate()` is supposed to be called just once.

Comment: I do not know why it does not work.
Should be easy. I think I will use socket

Comment: Aww, come on.  That flushing is definitely necessary, believe me.  Been there, done that hundreds of times.  And it cannot do any harm.  I'll have a look into that `communicate` again to see what we should use instead, just a moment.

Comment: I changed my answer.  Give it a try :-)

Comment: thank you very much for your time. But even do not get it. I think I'm closer to the solution. I edited the question, try to explain it better. And thank you very much again.

Comment: You are sending command strings without trailing newlines from Python to Java, where in turn you use `in.readline()` to read them.  I guess this will wait for a never coming trailing newline.  Does the Java process really accept the incoming command and start doing anything?  If not, it would easily explain why the `p.stdout.readline()` on the Python side afterwards hangs.

Comment: I love you!. The problem was the \n in python code. Thank you very much! sorry for my stupidity